# using a stored procedure for login in c#

Tags: c#, .net, stored-procedures, ado.net

If I run a store procedure with two parameter values (admin, admin) 
(parameters : admin, admin)
I get the following message :

```
Session_UID   User_Group_Name      Sys_User_Name    
------------------------------------ -------------------------------------------------- -
NULLAdministratorsNTMSAdmin
No rows affected.
(1 row(s) returned)
@RETURN_VALUE = 0
Finished running [dbo].[p_SYS_Login].
```

To get the same message in c# I used the code following :

```
string strConnection = Settings.Default.ConnectionString;           
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnection))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        SqlDataReader rdr = null;
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "p_SYS_Login";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlParameter paramReturnValue = new SqlParameter();
        paramReturnValue.ParameterName = "@RETURN_VALUE";
        paramReturnValue.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
        paramReturnValue.SourceColumn = null;
        paramReturnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramReturnValue);

        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramGroupName);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramUserName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sys_Login", "admin");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sys_Password", "admin");

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            string test = (string)cmd.Parameters["@RETURN_VALUE"].Value;
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
               Console.WriteLine("test : " + rdr[0]);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string message = ex.Message;
            string caption = "MAVIS Exception";
            MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.OK;

            MessageBox.Show(
            message,
            caption,
            buttons,
            MessageBoxIcon.Warning,
            MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

but I get nothing in SqlDataReader rdr ; 
is there something I am missing ?

Comment: I haven't tried this, but I suspect that the `DataReader` classes only ever get populated with *result sets*, not return values.

Comment: Are you able to modify the stored procedure to return the success value in the result set instead of the return value? That may solve the problem.

Comment: ...and have you inspected the value of the `test` variable? It's completely ignored in the code after it was created and assigned.

Answer (score 0):

The value at column 0 `Session_UID` is null as you have shown so I think this may be the reason you are not getting anything here:

```
Console.WriteLine("test : " + rdr[0]);
```

but then as an aside you might get Null reference exception.

Still why don't you try this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Return Value: " + test);

while(rdr.Read()){
    Console.WriteLine("test: " + rdr[0]+"  " + rdr[1]+ "   " + rdr[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get back a return value, but no result rows, you shouldn't be using the `.ExecuteReader()` but rather the `.ExecuteNonQuery()` call:

```
try
{
    conn.Open();
    object result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    string test = (string)cmd.Parameters["@RETURN_VALUE"].Value;
    conn.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   ....
}
```

Also, since you have your `SqlCommand` in a `using....` block, there's really no point in the `finally` block of your try - the `using` statement will take care of that already.